# Polly Cache - InMemory

Tags: c#, polly

I was looking for a good example which describes implementing Polly caching in .net core 2.1 using the memory cache option. I got to a point configuring the cache settings on startup.

```
services.AddSingleton<Polly.Registry.IPolicyRegistry<string>, Polly.Registry.PolicyRegistry>((serviceProvider) =>
    {
        PolicyRegistry registry = new PolicyRegistry();
        registry.Add("myCachePolicy", Policy.CacheAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAsyncCacheProvider>().AsyncFor<HttpResponseMessage>(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));
        return registry;
    });
```

Comment: Do the examples on the project page at https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly.Caching.MemoryCache help?  If using this with `HttpClientFactory`, see also the [main Polly doco on Polly with HttpClientFactory](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory), and the [specific notes around CachePolicy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#use-case-cachepolicy)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. All these links just gives u a start and no example shows how to cache really a controller method

Comment: Update Code formatting

Comment: Updated the code with formating

Comment: If you have downstream calls your controller is making whose results you wish to cache, execute the downstream call through a CachePolicy as shown in the [Polly cache documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Cache#using-cachepolicy). There is no built-in way to (eg) attribute a controller method to make its results cached by Polly's CachePolicy. For that, consider .NET Core's [in-built response caching middleware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-2.1), which is sensitive to which requests should/should not be cached.

Comment: CAn anyone post an example where we use ttlStrategy  and which only caches only HttpStatusCode.OK

Comment: Could you please provide with a way to (eg) attribute a controller method to make its results cached by Polly's CachePolicy

Comment: mountain traveller Could you please provide with a way to (eg) attribute a controller method to make its results cached by Polly's CachePolicy

Comment: Re: attributing a controller method: see answers on the similar question posted on github: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/521

Comment: Re: cache only HttpStatusCode.Ok.  See [cache documentation on the Polly wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Cache#caching-responses-only-selectively)