# Polly Cache - InMemory Action filter Implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, polly

Can anyone advise on implementing a polly cache at action filter level. I was able to implement in the action methods but didn't find a really good example of implementing in the action filter way.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896987/ . See answers on the similar question posted on github: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/521